# How the find the all the ranges of all strings between quotation marks

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I have been working on this problem for a couple of days but can't find a solution to it. I have a very long string that contains a lot of quotes and I want to be able to find all of the strings (the ranges of this strings) so that I can bold them using `NSMutableAttributedString`

Example
This is a string "with quoted" text and there is "some more" quoted text.
I want to be able to turn this string into the following:
This is a string **"with quoted"** text and there is **"some more"** quoted text.

This is what I have so far but it won't do the rest of the string:

```
    - (void)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString*)end inString:(NSMutableAttributedString *)text
     {
          NSRange startRange = [[text string] rangeOfString:start];
          if (startRange.location != NSNotFound)
          {
              NSRange targetRange;
              targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
              targetRange.length = [text length] - targetRange.location;
              NSRange endRange = [[text string] rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];
              if (endRange.location != NSNotFound)
              {
                  targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
                 [text addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0] range:targetRange];
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Have you heard about NSRegularExpression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If text is too  long this could be little bit slow however it works. Working on Regex solution.

```
NSString *string = @"Example This is a string \"with quoted1\" text and there is \"some more1\" quoted text. I want to be able to turn this string into the following: This is a string \"with quoted2\" text and there is \"some more2\" quoted text.";

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:nil];

int leftFromLeft = 0;

while ([string rangeOfString:@"\""].location != NSNotFound) {

    NSRange quoteLocationFirst  = [string
                                   rangeOfString:@"\""
                                   options:0
                                   range:NSMakeRange(leftFromLeft, string.length - leftFromLeft)
                                   ];

    leftFromLeft = quoteLocationFirst.location + quoteLocationFirst.length;

    NSRange quoteLocationSecond = [string
                                   rangeOfString:@"\""
                                   options:0
                                   range:NSMakeRange(leftFromLeft, string.length - leftFromLeft)
                                   ];

    NSRange quotedTextRange = NSMakeRange(
                                  quoteLocationFirst.location,
                                  quoteLocationSecond.location - quoteLocationFirst.location + 1
                                  );

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:quotedTextRange];

    NSLog(@"%@ \r\n\r\n", [string substringWithRange:quotedTextRange]);

    leftFromLeft = quoteLocationSecond.location + quoteLocationSecond.length;

    if ([string rangeOfString:@"\"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(leftFromLeft, string.length - leftFromLeft)].location == NSNotFound) {
        string = @"";
    }
}
```

## Edit

Regex solution appears to be better/faster.

```
NSString *string = @"Example This is a string \"with quoted1\" text and there is \"some more1\" quoted text. I want to be able to turn this string into the following: This is a string \"with quoted2\" text and there is \"some more2\" quoted text. Example This is a string \"with quoted3\" text and there is \"some more3\" quoted text. I want to be able to turn this string into the following: This is a string \"with quoted4\" text and there is \"some more4\" quoted text.";

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:nil];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"([^\"]*)\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in arrayOfAllMatches) {

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:match.range];

    //NSLog(@"%@", [string substringWithRange:match.range]);
}
```

Comment: you are the man! the Regex did work a lot better thanks a lot!